# Why does this loop return a divide by zero error?

Tags: java, math

I need to find an efficient way to square longs up to 10^13. I have the following code in Java:

```
static boolean squarefree(long number) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % (i*i) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This returns a divide by zero error, yet `i` is not zero at any point, so I'm not sure why I am getting that error. The reason I did not use `Math.pow(i ,2)` is because I felt that it would be much slower than just multiplying the number by itself.

[image: error]

Does anyone know why this error is occuring, or how I can efficiently square numbers

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE > Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: If `number>=2147483648`, i will never reach it, because that's more than int can handle. Instead it will overflow, go back to zero and ... division by zero.

Comment: You're most likely experiencing integer overflow.  Your loop variable is `int` but you want it to handle `long` values.

Comment: You actually _do_ efficiently square numbers, but the result probably overflows the `int` type capacity.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @Lino determine if a number is squarefree... the problem was that there was an integer overflow in the loop

Comment: Instead of trying to "efficiently square numbers", try to optimize your algorithm.

Comment: @Lino See the function's name. :)

Comment: @CiaPan oh, didn't know that this was a [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) mathematical term :)

Comment: @Kitswas answer gives a better algorithm but you *could* also eliminate the problem with a slightly more complicated test: `if ((number % i == 0) && ((number / i) % i == 0)) {`

Comment: @GhostCat Nope. The expression `number % (i*i) == 0` does not test whether `number` _is_ a  perfect square but rather if it is _a multiple_ of a square.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing an [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

The function below resolves this issue.

```
    static boolean isSquareFree(long number) {
        long upperLimit = (long) Math.sqrt(number);
        for (long i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
            if (number % (i*i) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

### Algorithm explained

We are trying to determine if a number is [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).

The largest integer (i) whose square perfectly divides the number (n) can be expressed as

```
i = floor(sqrt(n))
```

For example, `81 = 9^2`.
Therefore checking upto `upperLimit = (long) Math.sqrt(number)` is sufficient.
Now,
Since `upperLimit` is less than or equal to the square root of `number`, which fits in the datatype `long`,
we can rest assured that its square will also fit in type `long`.

Hence, we won't have any more [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)s.

Answer (score 1):

When your `number` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then your loop will never quit.

Bad thing is, `i` will overflow to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`) and from there starts to approach `0` from the negative direction (due to `i++`).

Once it reaches zero, `i * i` will still yield `0` and that's why you get that exception.

As mentioned in the comments, changing `int i` to `long i` would *maybe* resolve that problem. When you're starting to work with even bigger numbers, you may have to resort to using `BigInteger` or some other algorithm.